# Поиск метода для сокращения условий выбора

Tags: python, telebot

пытаюсь реализовать бота на Python 3.10 при помощи библиотеки pyTelegramBotApi(telebot). У меня есть in-line-клавиатура, но в обработчике handler условия elif занимают много места. Подскажите, как можно упростить код?

```
import telebot
from functions_line import *
from Logos import *
from telebot.types import InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton

bot = telebot.TeleBot("TOKEN")


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, LOGOS['NTBVAPE'], caption = 'Добро пожаловать в нашего бота!\nВыберите одного из производителей:', reply_markup = Product_from_keyboard())


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_query(call):
    if call.data == "NEZAVOD":
        bot.answer_callback_query(call.id, "Принято! Выбран производитель НЕЗАВОД")
        msg = bot.send_photo(call.message.chat.id, LOGOS['NEZAVOD'] ,caption = "Выберите линейку жидкостей ", reply_markup= XYLINET_LINE())
    elif call.data == "GRADEVAPE":
        bot.answer_callback_query(call.id, "Принято! Выбран производитель GRADE VAPE")
        bot.send_photo(call.message.chat.id, LOGOS['GRADEVAPE'] ,caption = "Выберите линейку жидкостей ", reply_markup= XYLINET_LINE())
    elif call.data == "HOTSPOT":
        bot.answer_callback_query(call.id, "Принято! Выбран производитель HOTSPOT")
        bot.send_photo(call.message.chat.id, LOGOS['HOTSPOT'] ,caption = "Выберите линейку жидкостей ", reply_markup= XYLINET_LINE())
    elif call.data == "TRAINLAB":
        bot.answer_callback_query(call.id, "Принято! Выбран производитель TRAIN LAB & ЖМЫХ LABS ")
        bot.send_photo(call.message.chat.id, LOGOS['TRAINLAB'] ,caption = "Выберите линейку жидкостей ", reply_markup= XYLINET_LINE())
    elif call.data == "SK":
       bot.answer_callback_query(call.id, "Принято! Выбран производитель SK (SK-360, SKAI) ")
       bot.send_photo(call.message.chat.id, LOGOS['SK'] ,caption = "Выберите линейку жидкостей ", reply_markup= XYLINET_LINE())
    elif call.data == "GANGLIQUIDS":
       date = bot.answer_callback_query(call.id, "Принято! Выбран производитель GANGLIQUIDS")
       bot.send_photo(call.message.chat.id, LOGOS['GANGLIQUIDS'] ,caption = "Выберите линейку жидкостей ", reply_markup= XYLINET_LINE())
    elif call.data == "DARKVAPELAB":
       bot.answer_callback_query(call.id, "Принято! Выбран производитель DARKVAPELAB")
       bot.send_photo(call.message.chat.id, LOGOS['DARKVAPELAB'] ,caption = "Выберите линейку жидкостей ", reply_markup= XYLINET_LINE())

    #Выбор линеек жидкостей
    elif call.data == "XNCOLD":
        bot.answer_callback_query(call.id, "Принято! XYLINET COLD")
    elif call.data == "XNCLASSIC":
        bot.answer_callback_query(call.id, "Принято! XYLINET CLASSIC")
    #######################################################################
    elif call.data == "FRCLASSIC":
        bot.answer_callback_query(call.id, "Принято! XYLINET COLDE")
    elif call.data == "FRX":
        bot.answer_callback_query(call.id, "Принято! XYLINET CLASSICR")
    #######################################################################

bot.infinity_polling()
```

Comment: Вы хоть код покажите ‍♀️

Comment: @Amgarak внес правки в вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно пойти в сторону словаря и сделать примерно так:

```
actions = {
    "NEZAVOD": ("Принято! Выбран производитель НЕЗАВОД", LOGOS['NEZAVOD']),
    "GRADEVAPE": ("Принято! Выбран производитель GRADE VAPE", LOGOS['GRADEVAPE']),
    "HOTSPOT": ("Принято! Выбран производитель HOTSPOT", LOGOS['HOTSPOT']),
    "TRAINLAB": ("Принято! Выбран производитель TRAIN LAB & ЖМЫХ LABS ", LOGOS['TRAINLAB']),
    "SK": ("Принято! Выбран производитель SK (SK-360, SKAI) ", LOGOS['SK']),
    "GANGLIQUIDS": ("Принято! Выбран производитель GANGLIQUIDS", LOGOS['GANGLIQUIDS']),
    "DARKVAPELAB": ("Принято! Выбран производитель DARKVAPELAB", LOGOS['DARKVAPELAB']),
    "XNCOLD": ("Принято! XYLINET COLD", None),
    "XNCLASSIC": ("Принято! XYLINET CLASSIC", None),
    "FRCLASSIC": ("Принято! XYLINET COLDE", None),
    "FRX": ("Принято! XYLINET CLASSICR", None),
}

def process_callback(call):
    message, photo = actions[call.data]
    bot.answer_callback_query(call.id, message)
    if photo:
        bot.send_photo(call.message.chat.id, photo, caption=message, reply_markup=XYLINET_LINE())

for data in actions.keys() 
    if call.data == data:
        process_callback(call)
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, пытался внедрить еще один handler, но вижу тут все более просто